# Move storage from root filesystem to volume in a digitalocean droplet

Tags: btrfs, nextcloud, digital-ocean

I started with a small server of 50G and setup a nextCloud instance. This space was not sufficient at the end. Now i added another volume. but i dont know how to move the data to that volume. The filesystem is btrfs and the new volume is ext4

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     977M     0  977M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     391M  6.1M  385M   2% /run
/dev/vda5      btrfs      49G   48G  294M 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     977M     0  977M   0% /tmp
/dev/vda2      ext4      966M  104M  797M  12% /boot
/dev/vda3      vfat      100M   12M   89M  12% /boot/efi
/dev/vda5      btrfs      49G   48G  294M 100% /home
/dev/sda       ext4      100G   24K   95G   1% /mnt/volume_fra1_01
tmpfs          tmpfs     196M  4.0K  196M   1% /run/user/1000
```

My question is where are all the photos and videos stored in the server and how to move the data to the volume? As i understand i cannot extend the / in the droplet

Update: files looks to be in /var/lib/docker/volumes/nextcloud_aio_nextcloud_data/_data/admin/files/ mounted on the container